# I have one excel spreadsheet with 1251 rows and one with 1800 rows. How might I find the 549 rows that are not in the 1251 row sheet?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

The 1251 rows are in the 1800 row sheet. How should I go about finding the 549 that are unique to the 1800 row sheet. Upon googling, I come across VLOOKUPs and Microsoft Spreadsheet Compare. I have no experience with either of these. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @pnuts all columns if possible

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are comparing column A between the two sheets, in a spare column in your sheet with 1800 rows, use the formula... : `=countif('BiggerSheet'!A1, 'SmallerSheet'!$A$1:$A$1251)` Copy that formula down Row 1 to Row 1800. That will return the number of rows where A1 in the BiggerSheet has a match in the SmallerSheet. If it's 0, then the value is unique to the BiggerSheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Microsoft Query on your workbook. Ensure that your two columns or sets of data are named ranges.  Open Data>From Other Sources>Microsoft Query, then choose Excel Files, navigate to your file, and open the query.

Then, after open the query, insert a SQL statement with something like

```
Select * FROM Case1 Case1 WHERE Case1.ID NOT IN(Select Distinct ID FROM Case2 Case2)
```

You could use the criteria adder for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try and concatenate the entire row on your first sheet and then on your second sheet. Then just use vlookup to match the value and see which rows are not missing.

more on concatenate read [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx)